# Ruby on Rails - Regroup data from two models in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, model

I have the "picture" model and "movie" model. In the index view, I would like to show them in the "created_at" order without looking if this is a movie or a picture. The only thing I struggle with is how to loop through both of this models in the same loop.
 This is how I loop for a single model in the view.
For movie model :

```
<% @movies.each do |m| %>
...
<%end%>
```

For picture model :

```
<% @pictures.each do |m| %>
...
<%end%>
```

And both of this model are already order by date "created_at" :

```
  def index
    @galeries = Galerie.order('created_at DESC')
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(@movies + @pictures).sort_by { |model| model.created_at }
```